# ActiveAdmin: Generating drop down list in form for has_many/belongs_to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have `Gallery` and `Image` models with has_many/belongs_to relationship.

My admin_active form for Image looks like this:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Image Details" do
    f.input :gallery_id
    f.input :file
  end
end
```

Instead or entering number for gallery_id I'd like to chose gallery name from drop-down list. By deafault this form looks like this, but I don't know how to do this manually.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Image Details" do
    f.input :gallery
    f.input :file
  end
end
```

Answer (score 13):

Change your form to the following

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Image Details" do
    f.input :gallery_id, as: :select, collection: Gallery.select(:name).uniq
    f.input :file
  end
end
```

Comment: I have :name in Gallery, active_admin by deafault is doing this dropdown list, without me having to create new class method. Any idea how?

Comment: Ok, I updated this line: `f.input :gallery_id, as: :select, collection: Gallery.select(:name).uniq`.

Comment: Yeah, it does... I just added the class method in case you wanted to manipulate it better. You could just do `f.input :gallery_id, as: :select, collection: Gallery.all`

Comment: I like that, updated my answer if anyone has the same problem.